# wanting images to sit next to each other, not below

Tags: html

I'm trying to make the images on my tumblr site sit next to each other, instead of above each other. I've made various attempts at following suggestions I've found on forums, but can't get it to work, so asking my first forum question.

This is the page I'm working on: http://dieinsel.tumblr.com/stories

I have more images to add (and each image is a link). I'd like the images to tile next to each other (with some space in between).

I've deleted all my attempts at changing the HTML, so it's back to the original:

```
<p><a href="http:blah"><img src="https:blah.jpg" /></a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="http:blah2"><img src="https:blah2.jpg" /></a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="http:blah3" style="line-height: 1.4;"><img src="https:blah3.jpg" /></a></p>
```

Comment: Hmm, try to set your images to `display: inline-block;` or `float: left;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a CSS like :

```
.caption img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 30px auto 30px auto;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

You have to change it to :

```
.caption img {
    display: inline-block; // Here change block to inline-block
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 30px auto 30px auto;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

### **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9cK5z/)**

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you! I was still trying (I'm very slow at this), but you've saved my brain cells a bit. Now I'm trying to work out how to widen the block that the images are sitting in to fit 3 or 4 images per line... I'll slowly work it out even if it takes me another day, but if you're able to help, that would be amazing.

Comment: Set `.narrow` class like : `.narrow {
max-width: 650px;
margin: auto;
}` to have 3 images per line. If you want more, increase `max-width`. If `.narrow` isn't enough, look for its parents.

Answer (score -1):

You're going to want to style the images (or their containers) with `display:inline-block` or `float: left/right` & give them a `margin` to get your spacing.

Comment: Thankyou! Are you able to post something that I can just copy and paste?

Comment: (or is that cheating?)

Comment: You should make an attempt at it and post that code here, then we can look at where the issues might be and help you correct them.